# InstaPy / "Too few images, skipping this tag"

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instapy

I'm basically building an Instagram bot using InstPy module. When I try to make it like posts from a specific tag and follow 50% of the posts' accounts, it checks for posts with the tag, but it says "Too few images, skipping this tag". What should I do?

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="<username>", password="<password>", headless_browser=True)
session.login()
session.like_by_tags(["modernwarfare", "callofduty"])
session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=50)
session.end()
```

**Shell**

```
................................................................
INFO [2020-09-15 21:54:10] [username]  Logged in successfully!
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
INFO [2020-09-15 21:54:10] [username]  Saving account progress...
INFO [2020-09-15 21:54:25] [username]  Tag [1/2]
INFO [2020-09-15 21:54:25] [username]  --> b'modernwarfare'
INFO [2020-09-15 21:54:52] [username]  Too few images, skipping this tag
INFO [2020-09-15 21:54:52] [username]  Tag [2/2]
INFO [2020-09-15 21:54:52] [username]  --> b'callofduty'
INFO [2020-09-15 21:55:20] [username]  Too few images, skipping this tag
INFO [2020-09-15 21:55:20] [username]  Liked: 0
INFO [2020-09-15 21:55:20] [username]  Already Liked: 0
INFO [2020-09-15 21:55:20] [username]  Commented: 0
INFO [2020-09-15 21:55:20] [username]  Followed: 0
INFO [2020-09-15 21:55:20] [username]  Inappropriate: 0
INFO [2020-09-15 21:55:20] [username]  Not valid users: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I  think you've been tracked as a bot. Leave it rest for a few hours then change the password of your account and try again.

Comment: But it happened from the first time I run the code.

Comment: Does it if you change the tags?

Comment: Yes it happened. But I edited the code and it works fine, excepts that it is very very slow. Could I make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by editing the code a little bit. I added the session.set_quota_supervisor(enabled=True, peak_comments_daily=240, peak_comments_hourly=21) line so Instagram did not identify me as a bot and block me.

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="username", password="password", headless_browser=True)
session.login()
session.set_quota_supervisor(enabled=True, peak_comments_daily=240, peak_comments_hourly=21)
session.like_by_tags(["modernwarfare", "callofduty"])
session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=50)
session.end()
```